# Xamarin.iOS build error System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I get this error when I try to build using a distribution provisioning profile

```
Error       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: /Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/iOSClient/f4287e1ce437e3e2197bfddb3a942d82/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/optimized/Default-736h@3x.png does not exist
File name: '/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/iOSClient/f4287e1ce437e3e2197bfddb3a942d82/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/optimized/Default-736h@3x.png'
  at System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName, System.Boolean overwrite) [0x001bd] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:112 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.CopyFile (System.String source, System.String target, System.String targetItemSpec) [0x0002d] in <4ed71c0d8bd847c3bc4130be1482dce1>:0 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.Execute () [0x00116] in <4ed71c0d8bd847c3bc4130be1482dce1>:0    iOSClient
```

any ideas what the cause might be?

Comment: The error says you're missing an image: `Default-736h@3x.png does not exist`. Can you double check that you have one set for your project? You can view this forum post for more information: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24788/iphone-6-6-launch-image-names

Comment: it builds fine with debug provisioning profile, only happens on distribution ones so the image must be ok right?

Comment: It might be a bad cache. On your mac, delete the `/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/iOSClient/f4287e1ce437e3e2197bfddb3a942d82` cache and rebuild your project to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I deleted everything under /Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/ a few times and clean/rebuilt, no luck!

Comment: Double check that you can open up that image in an image tool to ensure it's not corrupted/etc. Make sure it's not different than other images that aren't causing an issue. Follow the exact path `/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/iOSClient/f4287e1ce437e3e2197bfddb3a942d82/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/optimized/Default-736h@3x.png` to ensure it's there.

Comment: as strange as it may sound, the build error went  away after I built from anoher pc which is connected to the same build server, and now it builds fine on my pc as well.

Comment: and now the error is back again :))))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution in this case was to delete everything under C:\Users[current user]\AppData\Local\Xamarin.